# Equivalent of on-slide-changed for ion-slides

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, slider, swiper.js

I am migrating from ion-slide-box to ion-slides.

I was using on-slide-changed with ion-slide-box like this:

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" show-pager="false">
```

but I can't find the equivalent for ion-slides :

```
<ion-slides on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" options="data.sliderOptions" slider="data.slider" >
```

I am using Ionic 1 as you can see.

Comment: why do you want to use on-slide-changed api in ion-slide tag?

Comment: The logics in my code requires me to detect the index of the slide at each change, because i need to do something particular on the last slide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is no API build as `on-slide-changed` for `<ion-slides>` it is only for `<ion-slide-box>` only.

But you can use events directly for ion-slides like this:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeStart", function(event, data){
  console.log('Slide change is beginning');
});

$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeEnd", function(event, data){
  // note: the indexes are 0-based
  $scope.activeIndex = data.slider.activeIndex;
  $scope.previousIndex = data.slider.previousIndex;
});
```

So you can call your function like this:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeStart", function(event, data){
   $scope.slideChanged(data.slider.activeIndex);
});
```

Cheers :)